# Trim title at side bare

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress theme has a "save post as a favortite" function. And it marks the post as a favorite at side bar. but it wont shorten the title. the long titles at sidebar looks messy. in function i use:

```
   function short_title( $after = '', $length ) {
        $mytitle = get_the_title();
        if( mb_strlen( $mytitle ) > $length ) {
            $mytitle = mb_substr( $mytitle, 0, $length );
            echo $mytitle . $after;
        } else echo $mytitle;
    }
```

and i call it with:

```
<?php short_title( '...', 99 ); ?>
```

how can i put short_title in to here:

```
        echo '</p>';
        echo '<h4><a href="' . $curr_perma . '" rel="nofollow">' . stripslashes( strip_tags( $post_obj_fave->post_title ) ) . '</a></h4>';
        echo '<p class="info">';
```

Comment: I do not see where is the title function inside the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the shorten title function to `$post_obj_fave->post_title`

So change your code from:

```
echo '<h4><a href="' . $curr_perma . '" rel="nofollow">' . stripslashes( strip_tags( $post_obj_fave->post_title ) ) . '</a></h4>';
```

To:

```
echo '<h4><a href="' . $curr_perma . '" rel="nofollow">' . stripslashes( strip_tags( shorten_title($post_obj_fave->post_title, $length=99) ) ) . '</a></h4>';
```

Now create a function for `shorten_title()`

Here it is:

```
 function shorten_title($var, $length ) {

        if( mb_strlen( $var ) > $length ) {
            $var= mb_substr( $var, 0, $length );
            return $var;
        } else return $var;
    }
```

This should shorten the passed variable ($post_obj_fave->post_title) in this case according to associated length.